# Auto comments on reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I reviewed some low quality posts earlier and got a comment back from another user telling me that I should flag the comment rather than copying someone elses text (they didn't realise it was an auto comment)..

Is this a new feature (or bug?), I'm not against the auto comments, I'd just prefer to know when I'm being auto-spoken for.

[Post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25867354/1324033)
[image]

[Another auto post from today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25868298/1324033)

Comment: I think it would be useful if auto comments were more clearly labelled, so that the recipient knows what it is. I've had it happen a few times that people responded to an auto comment, assuming it was something I actually typed. One time I was blasted (with a later apology) for leaving a "link only" (?) comment on a 4 year old answer. I don't routinely look at the post date when things show up in the review queue. So I had to explain to the poster that I wasn't picking on their post, but simply casting votes on posts in the review queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Except for "No comment", **all** review options add the text as an auto-comment.

Comment: Is this new? and if not then shouldn't my new comment really just be a +1 to Divya's post so I don't look a little bit silly?

Comment: It's not new. Normally, they are just counted up. However, Divya's post looks different, like copied in there by hand as a normal comment. That's why yours got posted anyway.