# Add indication that canned comments are from review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, comments

I've had more than a few new users take the low quality review comments personally, some even going as far as arguing, revenge voting, and so on... I find myself needing to explain the review process fairly often.

I'm thinking we could clear up a lot of misunderstanding and animosity, by giving some indication that the canned comments from the review queues are a part of how the system works and that the reviewers aren't just random users trolling through looking to bash on posts.

A simple link to the [Access Review Queues privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) or some other relevant help center page could work.

Something like:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. – [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) – ExampleUser 5 mins ago

Comment: Why should comments from review be treated any differently than comments you leave manually? If you would not type the same comment yourself below the answer, perhaps you shouldn't be clicking that button in review.

Comment: @BradLarson Its more about explaining how the review system works to new users, giving them a heads up that their post landed in a review queue and that they weren't just being singled out by a random user.

Comment: The ones responding angrily to review comments on answers tend to be more experienced users, from what I've observed, and a lot of them are responding to completely wrong review comments ("this is not an answer"-type ones to very clear answers, etc.). We clean up a lot of these comments, mainly left by reviewers who aren't paying attention to the buttons they're clicking. A surprising number of on-the-mark review comments actually lead to positive behavior on the part of the answerer (fleshing out code-based or link-based answers, for example).

Comment: I don't know that stating where a comment comes from will cause a significant change in the behavior of the answerer when presented with such a comment, based on what I've seen so far.

Comment: @BradLarson I had one case where an experienced user (20k+) got very testy in response to one of these automated comments. It was a LQ (link only, I believe) vote on a 5 year old answer. As soon as I explained that this was an automated comment from a vote in the review queue, they apologized. In this case, knowing the source of the comment could have prevented an offensive response. While it's not a common scenario, I think it would be helpful to add a label that clarifies the source  of the comment.

Comment: In theory, I agree with Brad, but I've only had access to the LQP queue for ~1 month and I've already lost count of the number of times I've had to explain to users automated responses and where they come from. I see the problem, but I'm not sure I like this proposed solution.

Comment: It could also help make getting rid of these comments - if they are wrong - much easier. How about a single obsolete flag to delete?

Comment: I'm all for getting rid of them, I [recently asked a meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271466/1324033) because I was also receiving confused comments from users due to these auto-comments. It is much easier just to keep the `no comment required` button selected but that isn't much help to the user who just had their question closed.

Comment: The fix is rather simple, it really doesn't matter *who* posted this comment.  So instead of giving the user name, thus providing a target for more acrimony, it might as well be omitted.  Or, perhaps, more accurately attributed to the user that actually posted the comment, @Community.

Comment: @BoltClock Potential for flag spree abuse for users by querying data.SE for those comments just to collect a helpful flag.

Comment: I fail to see anything wrong with this. Automated messages should be marked as such, it's as simple as that.

Comment: I can understand that text which looks like boilerplate (what the text in question does) can sound a bit rude if it's not clear that it comes from some "system" (like a review system). +1

Comment: @HansPassant That would mean that a confused or questioning user had no one to direct their concerns to though.

Comment: Surely that's already covered by an existing meta question?  If not then it will be.

Comment: I am a user with over 300 reputation, I didn't know what the review queue even was... Something like that was definitely necessary - I always thought random people were just harsh when I posted something that didn't quite fit the standards.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This has been added in the latest build (thanks to [@m0sa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa)). When adding a comment through a queue, the comment will include a link to the review task. It will look like this:

> [image]

Comment: To the review _task_, listing the reviewers and their decisions? Looks like an invitation for more revenge downvotes.

Comment: @NormalHuman We are using the link as a way to help educate the answerer and provide more context to the comment. If they see that the community felt something was wrong, then the goal is that they will improve the answer or learn that they need to improve their answering ability.  It's entirely possible that a user could see the review of their answer without this link. As far as revenge voting, we'll be watching to see if there are any spikes due to these comments.

Comment: @bluefeet this feature marks a giant step towards user friendliness and TRANSPARENCY.  kudos.  UPVOTED :)

Comment: This is only for new comments right? Or has it been added to old comments? (can't find an example right now, which is why I'm asking! :/)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ New comments only; it was too much overhead to backfill the comments.

Comment: @bluefeet right, ok - thanks for the clarification! :) And for the feature ;)

Comment: Could it be that this broke the auto-upvoting if an existing comment is chosen? See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278902/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I'd suggest posting bug report, your comment _might_ get lost.

Answer (score 41):

I support this. I have seen multiple users get mad at the "boilerplate" nature of these comments, suggesting that A and B are colluding somehow since they left identical comments on different answers/questions - they must be working together to gang up on the poor user. For every user who posts this belief, there must be many more who just think it. They don't have access to the review queues, so they have no idea that these long and complicated sentences were added by software.

Why not make that clear to them? It's not hard, just adding a titch more text to the auto comment. If it prevents hard feelings it seems like a great idea to me.

Answer (score 4):

It might help as well if the text were only added once a consensus was reached, rather than when the first user clicks "link only" or whatever.

I realize the intent here might be to get users to improve their answers before they get deleted, but perhaps a better solution would be to give a grace period after consensus is reached and have the question re-submitted to the queue if an edit is made within a certain period of time.

Otherwise, you can get situations where one person clicks "link only" and another person clicks "should be a comment", etc... leading to conflicting recommendations.

Comment: So basically like voting for which auto-comment will be applied in the same way that voting for a close reason chooses which reason will be applied to the question, even if one or two of the closers voted for the wrong reason.