# What happens if I flag an answer that is already in the Low Quality review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts

Lately, I have started to flag bad content more, particularly answers, and was wondering about a particular scenario: What happens if I flag an answer that is already in the Low Quality review queue?

This would typically happen if someone else has already flagged the post before me. If I go on a flagging expedition on low quality newly arriving answers (including spam), this is quite likely, because many of them stick out like a sore thumb.

I looked through a few pages of search results on MSO and MSE. While I found some related topics, I didn't see anything that addressed this specific situation. I can think of three main possibilities how it might be handled:

1. My flag is treated as a "Recommend Deletion" vote in the Low Quality queue, just as if I had found it there and clicked the button.
2. The flag is automatically ignored, because it's redundant.
3. The flag still ends up in a moderator queue, and needs to be looked at by a moderator.

Option 1 would make the most sense to me. Option 2 also seems reasonable. The main reason I'm asking is that I hope it's not option 3. I know the moderators are a busy bunch, and I wouldn't want them to have to handle flags that don't really serve a purpose anymore.

So far, I have avoided flagging answers that already have comments that look like canned Low Quality review comments. Even though that is not always entirely clear ([Add indication that canned comments are from review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271829/add-indication-that-canned-comments-are-from-review) would come in handy here). But if the answer is option 1 from my list, I can go ahead and flag those anyway.

Comment: It will just stay in the queue where it is, and your flag will either be helpful, disputed, or declined. However, you will not be able to review it in the queue, since you flagged it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it helpful if multiple users flag a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293480/is-it-helpful-if-multiple-users-flag-a-question)

Comment: @gnat This is not a duplicate. The other question was about flagging questions, this is about flagging answers. This is also much older, and has an upvoted/accepted answer. If anything, it would make much more sense to duplicated in the other direction.

Answer (score 15):

**What happens if I flag an answer that is already in the Low Quality review queue?**

If multiple VLQ flags are raised on a post, it'll take multiple LQ reviewers to override them.
[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/):

> Each review task requires a minimum number of "Looks OK" reviews (2 on
>   SO, 1 everywhere else) to be dequeued; this number increases by one
>   for each pending flag on the post (edits, closing and deletion dequeue
>   the task in the normal fashion).

**My flag is treated as a "Recommend Deletion" vote in the Low Quality queue, just as if I had found it there and clicked the button**

No. Review Queue actions can only be done from the review page. Your flag will be counted as a new flag and it will not be treated as a Recommend Deletion vote.

**The flag is automatically ignored, because it's redundant**

No, flag is not ignored (flagging to close is an exception). In case a flag is raised to close a question then the flag does not enter mod queue. [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190613/):

> Close "flags" now merely place the question into the close review
>   queue - if the question is closed, the flag is marked helpful; if it
>   is not, the flag is declined.

**The flag still ends up in a moderator queue, and needs to be looked at by a moderator**

Yes, it will be added to the mod queue. However, if the community acts on the flagged post (such as deletion) then the flag would be removed from the mod queue and marked as helpful (or disputed in certain cases). Some flags such as 'mod attention required' may remain in the mod queue even after community has taken an action on the post.

[Related information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203217/) by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) on MSE:

> - **Spam** and **Offensive** can be automatically handled without moderator intervention at six flags, but are only visible to
>     moderators in the flags queue.
> - **Recommend Closure** flags (off-topic, unclear, et al) always go to the Close Votes queue (which requires 3k) and are always handled
>     automatically. Moderators do not see them in the flags queue.
> - **Custom Moderator Attention** flags can only be seen by moderators and *require* a moderator dismiss them in some way. They cannot be
>     automatically dismissed by a non-moderator action.
> - **Comment** flags can only be seen by moderators but can be automatically dismissed if the comment matches a certain auto-deletion
>     phrase or enough users flag it.
> - **Not an Answer** flags push the post into the Low Quality Posts queue. They are automatically dismissed if the answer gets deleted at
>     any point, but otherwise require a moderator to dismiss. Most of these
>     flags are handled in the Low Quality Posts queue without moderator
>     intervention.
> - **Very Low Quality** flags push the post into the Low Quality Posts queue (which requires 2k) after being active for 15 minutes. They are
>     generally auto-dismissed by community actions.
> - **Suggested Edits** on posts can be reviewed by any user who has full editing privileges, through the review queues.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - When flags go to the review queues where anyone can take action on them, users are not actually made aware of it being a flag that caused
>     the post to appear there.
> - Moderators *can* see flags on their own posts (and comments), but tend to avoid handling them.

Comment: Since NAA flags cause moderator flags: Do you know if they get consolidated? Say if 3 users flag the same post as NAA, will the moderators see 3 separate flags? Or one flag with an indication that 3 users raised it?

Comment: @RetoKoradi sorry no idea about the display of mod queue. However in both cases if the posts gets deleted all the flags would be dismissed as helpful. Btw, NAA flags push the post into the Low Quality Posts queue, so the community gets a chance to act on it first.