# Accessing review-queue from post

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Although it seems strange to me that this hasn't came up before I could not find any thread on meta discussing this topic, so here I go:

While looking over some questions I often stumble upon answers/questions that should definitely be in the low-quality review-queue and should have been recommended for deletion. But since I didn't access them via the review-queue I don't have access to the tools available there.

So here's my suggestion:
For posts on the low-quality review-queue (or any other appropriate queue) and if the user has access to the queue show a link that allows direct access to this specific item on the queue so I can take the appropriate action right away.

Any thoughts about it?

Comment: You can simply flag the answers appropriately.

Comment: I wish that were possible. I've seen it discussed on MSE. For example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212032/show-me-if-a-post-is-in-the-review-queue. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176131/link-to-review-on-post.

Comment: Different question, but related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272559/what-happens-if-i-flag-a-question-that-is-already-in-the-low-quality-review-queu.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If the post is already under review, raising another flag on it is not really useful. What you may want to do in this case is participated in the review, for example by casting a "Recommend Deletion" or "Looks OK" vote.

Comment: I agree, it should be similar to the current close votes system where we can cv a post in the review queue or directly using the close button on any post.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion That's inadequate too: we can vote to close a question from the page, but we can't vote to leave open if we think the closure votes are invalid, except by trawling the review history to try to find the post in the queue.