# Is it helpful if multiple users flag a question?

Tags: support, flags

When I come across a question that should be closed (for whatever reason), should I flag it if some else has already done so?  If I flag the question, should I write a comment so that others don't flag it as well?

I looked to see if this has already been asked and did not see it.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272559/what-happens-if-i-flag-a-post-that-is-already-in-the-low-quality-review-queue. That one was more about flagging answers, while yours is about flagging questions.

Comment: Always flag everything that needs it, and downvote if it needs it as well. This site is fundamentally based on consensus, 1 person is not a driving consensus.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is it helpful if multiple users flag a question?

In short: yes. If a close reason applies and the question is not salvageable by you, flag it for closure.

"Long" version: still yes...

Multiple flags on one post don't create additional work as long as they are of the same type.

### Close flags

Since you are below 3k, you don't see close votes (on other people's questions). It also means that you can only flag to close those questions, not vote to close them. This means that you don't see whether a question was voted/flagged to close. Even if somebody has explicitly written a comment that the question is e.g. too broad, doesn't mean that they voted/flagged as such. Maybe they forgot to do it or they want to give the asker some time to redeem themselves.

**Flag it**, because there is still a possiblity that it wasn't flagged. **Flag it**, because you might select a close reason that others didn't select which might be helpful when reviewers filter the review tasks by close reasons.

There are only two cases where you might know for sure that somebody voted/flagged to close *in the past* and those are for duplicates and custom close reasons. I emphasise the past, because the post might have dropped out of the review queues and the close votes might have aged away.

**Flag it**, if it still adheres to the current community consensus of what is currently close-worthy. If it is a recent comment, then the first paragraph applies.

Your flag can also help push the question back into a reviewable state if the last flag/vote was more than 4 days ago and two other users agree. ([Ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions))

### Spam/rude/offensive flags

As with close flags, you can't be sure that somebody actually flagged it. So, **flag it**.

But also, [this applies for spam/offensive flags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

> - 3 flags -- post is banished from the front page.
> - 6 flags -- post is locked, deleted, and the owner loses 100 reputation.

Every flag helps!

### Other flags (for moderator attention)

Again, you can't be sure a post was flagged with *other*. Moderators can see all flags on a post. If multiple people flagged the same post, then they can see everything at the same time and handle everything once.

If multiple people are constantly flagging for something and their flags are declined by a moderator, you can ask a question here on meta, why it was declined. Most of the time a moderator will chime in and tell you exactly why.

Comment: worth noting that amount of close flags also impacts [keeping / aging away / re-entering in The Queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/839601 "'FlagsThreshold: the number of votes or flags...'")

Comment: You're the link ninja of meta, @gnat! Always a helpful link machine!

Comment: For spam/offensive, you should always flag it to push it closer to the six flags required to delete it.  Thinking "well someone else already flagged it" just lets it hang around longer.

Comment: "Post is banished from the front page" - Do you mean "question" here, rather than "post"? I can't see how this applies to answers, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by banished from the front page.

Comment: @starsplusplus I copied it from the help page. I agree that answers don't appear on the front page. Maybe a bug report can be submitted here on meta.

Comment: If six spam flags can take away 100 rep from someone, could that not be abused by evil sockpuppet accounts to take revenge on someone ?

Comment: @Jonas It would be interesting to know if there was precedent for this. I somehow doubt this.

Comment: speaking of spam flags, SE team appears to [encourage more of these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293634/what-else-to-do-to-prevent-possible-deliberate-spamming-from-a-new-user/293653#comment190118_293653): "spam flags in particular help teach our spam mitigation system, so it's important to use that. Enough flags piling up on a spam post to cause it to be deleted sends a very clear signal to said system"

Answer (score 4):

Heck yes if the reason is spam or that the question is rude and offensive.

The reason behind it is that flagged posts are [automatically deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) when they reach a certain amount of them - thus avoiding to bother anyone in the process!

So if you see a question that should be closed - **flag it**! Indicating as such in the comments can be good to help people see *why* that question should be closed, and encourage them to flag it too.

That is as long as you don't flag for moderator intervention, or for duplicate/off-topic. This only puts it in a review queue, and thus there is no need to flag multiple times.

Comment: That only implies to spam and rude and abusive, the other flags push the posts into one of the review queues.

Comment: Content flagged as spam or offensive is auto-deleted after a certain threshold; that's not true for close flags, which have no effect except for pushing the question into the close votes review queue.

Comment: Thank you @ArunA.S, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @ArunA.S FWIW in Low Quality queue additional flags act as "countering" possible Looks OK votes, see [A single “looks good” should not mean the post is “good”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204691/165773)