# What else to do to prevent (possible deliberate) spamming from a new user

Tags: discussion, new-users, spam, users

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4874405/prabina-k-rout) is a member since today only.

I noticed, all his/her posts (question/answer) contains a link to a particular website. [E.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462373/difference-between-break-and-continue-statement/30098497#30098497):

[image: post sample]

Moreover, the posts themselves add no value. I think this is SPAM.

My action so far:

1. Downvote
2. Vote-to-close
3. Raised a Custom flag for moderator attention.

Anything else needs to be done from my side?

Comment: That's actually at least the second account today to spam those links. First one was the owner of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375544/double-dimensional-array-to-single-dimensional-array/30093217#30093217). Custom flag should be enough if you've described the issue clearly enough.

Comment: Might add that the site in question is really really crappy.

Comment: Why not just use the standard spam flag and be done with it?

Comment: @Yannis Please correct me if i'm wrong, but IMHO, spam flag is handled post-by-post basis, but here I wanted to make the moderators aware of the behavior of that particular user. I don't want to go and flag _all_ his/her post one-by-one.

Comment: The spam flag has the added benefit of feeding [SE's anti spam thingy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam/192847#192847) with data. However, you are correct, if we are talking about a lot of posts, a custom mod flag could be preferable. The anti-spam thingy will probably be fed the same data once the mod destroys the account for spamming.

Comment: Just got nuked.

Comment: Also notice that enough regulars in the [MSE Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) are active in raising SPAM flags network wide. If you stumble on something we have missed feel free to drop a link there.

Comment: Additional examples for those who want to examine them: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30098421), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30099202).

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes, SPAM-flags get handled on a post-by-post basis. But if you spam-flag, that a) trains the spam-filter b) deals with that post faster c) gets moderator attention much faster (spam and offensive flags get preferential treatment). If you see a pattern, you can also use a custom flag to make sure the mods know, but those need longer to be handled. Though there's synergy: The spam-flag attracts moderators faster, who will then see *all* flags on the post.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for the updates sir. :-)

Comment: @rene very useful. I'll keep that bookmarked, just in case. :-)

Comment: @Deduplicator Nice piece of information. I did not know the last part `who will then see all flags on the post`. Then the SPAM flag should be sufficient, isn't it? Thanks for shring. :-)

Comment: Again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136856/what-is-the-major-difference-between-nul-and-null

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If it's obvious from glancing at a post that it's true spam, a single spam flag is enough to let us know. An "other" flag describing the situation might be appropriate where it's not obvious why something is spam.

The only concern about "other" flags is that they don't float to the top of the moderator flag listing like spam flags do, and may get buried in the piles of unimportant "other" flags we get all the time. I know SE is working on better tools for this, but that's how it is right now.

If it's obviously spam and needs to be dealt with now, a spam flag might be more appropriate.

My standard workflow when I see a spam flag is this: If I identify a post as being clear spam, I'll typically hit it with a hard spam flag to destroy the post and get the anti-spam system to immediately block anything from that location. I'll then look at the user account and see if any other posts were missed (banning any reviewers who approved them). Finally, I'll do a search for that URL and for accounts at the same location to see if this is a larger pattern. I will destroy those other posts and accounts as needed.

For me at least, a single spam flag can be enough to point out a network of spammers that need to be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the clarification. So, now on, "SPAM" flag it is. :-)

Comment: Note that, spam flags in particular help teach our spam mitigation system, so it's important to use that. Enough flags piling up on a spam post to cause it to be deleted sends a very clear signal to said system :)

Comment: @TimPost OMG user is back... http://stackoverflow.com/users/4877519/prabina-k-rout

Comment: If a post is flagged as spam, do you tend to check other flags on the post at the same time? That could help with the "other flags aren't looked at right away" issue if so.

Comment: @ChrisHayes - Generally, yes. All flags on a post tend to be processed in one action (which can sometimes lead to odd declines due to race conditions where a new flag comes in just as another is being declined). If an "other" flag is on something that has also been flagged as spam, that flag generally is visible at the time we handle the spam flag.