# May we have some "canned comments"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

On Stack Overflow, certain comments get repeated a lot. Just off  the top of my head:

```
    1. Do you have any more code to show? This post lacks enough detail.

    2. Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is off-topic here. Please see this link.

    3. Please make  a more descriptive title, as the current title is too broad.

    4. That is not valid code, it will not compile (thanks Plutonix!)

    5. Please properly format code, Click here to learn how
```

As user [PlasmaTT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/833362/plasmahh) says, response to "why comment when you can downvote?" :

> The point is that often giving the message is a good thing to do. The
>   words chosen is secondary. Should we wait for someone having the time
>   and state of mind to reformulate the same thing a gazillionth time for
>   others to not notice that this was reiterated endlessly elsewhere, or
>   should we give people a tool that frees their time to do other useful
>   things?

It would be nice if we had macros or shortcuts for comments. Just to speed it up a little.

Because... Less typing!

Having them built-into Stack Overflow is nice because we can use the feature from anywhere.

I personally like what Plasma suggested, via macros :

```
__WHATHAVEYOUTRIED__ would expand to a variety of versions asking what you have tried
```

To prevent newbie-abuse, it should be a privilege that is granted after a reasonable mark.

What thinks Meta?

Comment: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: a) *That code hurts my eyes` b) *Clearly, you need more college*  c) *Are you trapping for the `ItNotWorkingException` ?*  d) *Yes, it is possible*  e) *That is not valid code, it wont compile*

Comment: I'd love to see such comments integrated natively into the site - the userscript is good but that's a pain to install and sync (especially if using the site from different computers and browsers, some of which doesn't support userscripts).

Comment: @AndréDaniel  - `using the site from different computers and browsers` - thanks for this point!

Comment: *I have the answer to this, and it is easy to fix.  However, you and your 62% Accept Rate can go pound sand.*

Comment: There used to be a meta question (that got summarily deleted) called "What Stackoveflow Is Not".  [It no longer exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted).  I suspect the reason for its annhilation is similar to the reason such pro-forma comments have not been integrated.  That reason: it's better to provide context-sensitive comments that speak to a particular question than it is to provide canned responses that have a higher likelihood of being unhelpful to the OP.  (I say this as a fan of the deleted meta question. :( )

Comment: `We are not code makers, show us some codes which failed.`

Comment: @howaboutNO: **Pro tip:** It's not called *"codes."*

Comment: Ironically longer TL;DR of above comment: "@howaboutNO: how about NO?"

Comment: And can we use 'Yes' and 'No' even though they are < 15 chars.?

Comment: @TaW , yessssss?

Comment: @TaW - I find it hard to believee "yes" and "no" are disallowed !

Comment: Supposing that the "canned comments" are to be implemented, would it be actual buttons or  special-keywords? Perhaps if you need to enter a macro manually, it is not as accessible to abuse (i.e if it was simply a menu then people would use it more, but via macros it forces some thoughtfulness )

Comment: Downvote, vote to close, move on. Too much time is spent being a janitor to also have to now remember canned comments and then actually wait for the OP to most likely not even respond.

Comment: Use of the Pro-Forma comments extension used to be _really common_ in PHP, and I absolutely hated it. It was so impersonal and often condescending to the OPs.  For one reason or another (I don't hang out in PHP chat, where most of it originated) it seems to have mostly evaporated and I'm glad about that. I don't mind for myself, often typing _similar_ comments instead of rubber-stamping the _same_ one.

Comment: I dunno, the main point is that we often find ourselves typing out the same dreary phrases "hey tie your shoes please"  , I echo Andre  `In most cases, the alternative is a poor comment. Displacing those with a good canned comment .. net benefit.`

Comment: @Coffee - And what % of well intentioned comments are ever actually actioned by the OP? In my experience, a *very* low one.

Comment: Ok fine I'll make my own canned repertoire

Comment: @TravisJ - Admittedly, but this is human behavior. We sometimes *should* give the downvote and ignore treatment ... but  we rarely do it. I doubt that will change either. But I'd argue a boring auto-comment is better than downvotes alone.

Comment: @Coffee - Yup, definitely better for the user. They would also rather see you just answer their question **right now**. According to them there is never a reason to downvote. They don't need to educate themselves, because they are not the problem here. Perhaps I am slightly biased from seeing so many poor questions posted by users who clearly do not even care enough to respond to multiple comments on their post or even answers to their question.

Comment: I also want canned hugs.

Comment: @Trilarion Travis et al `[[__HUGS_FOR_HOPE__]]`

Comment: @TravisJ - Well, yeah that is a bummer no doubt. A class of users are pure leach and nothing more

Comment: @Coffee - Not trying to insinuate anything, your question here is an interesting topic :) But for users who post questions which would need a canned comment, in my opinion, they are easily categorized by their tone, consideration (or lack thereof), effort, and research. I enjoy helping someone who came across something that was clearly complex, an edge case, or who just got stuck. I absolutely cannot stand running in to a brick wall of unformatted code with a vague description and a complete lack of attentiveness. I feel like the latter situation is not remedied by any class of comment.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50030/canned-reasons-for-up-down-vote-w-example-of-how-it-would-work

Answer (score 36):

People don't like canned comments.

We already use comments like these in the review queues to provide feedback to users whose posts end up there, and [feedback usually isn't positive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271829/add-indication-that-canned-comments-are-from-review). This is especially true when people don't understand where the comments come from and proceed to get into arguments defending their "great" post, assuming that the people who "leave" these comments are part of the [Meta police](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268240/what-does-meta-police-mean), and that they're just copy-and-pasting the same comment on every post they see.

Such as it is, I can imagine this turning out quite badly; if we hand everyone over a certain reputation limit the ability to auto-comment, they will use that ability, and they will probably use it in places where it's not supposed to be used, thus enraging the new users whom I presume you are trying to help out here.

Close votes are very effective, and while many new users won't check this, they're available under all of your own posts (even if you have <3k reputation). Those close reasons are pretty well thought-out, and they are intended to give this kind of auto-feedback to the user anyway.

We've seen this kind of problem before with the ["What have you tried?" epidemic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic), and it ended in a block of comments consisting of that phrase.

All things considered, I prefer the way we have it now. If you really want canned comments, use this [great userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and the [repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments).

Otherwise, craft a comment unique to the situation (which is the best thing you can do) or simply don't leave a comment at all.

Also, [relevant Meta.SE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117963/formal-adoption-of-pro-forma-comments-script-into-se-engine-proper).

Comment: The kind of people that don't like canned comments at all would also not like non-canned comments at all that say the same thing, thus that point is moot.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Right, but the point is not to give them to everyone, encouraging their use.

Comment: The point is that often giving the message is a good thing to do. The words chosen is secondary. Should we wait for someone having the time and state of mind to reformulate the same thing a gazillionth time for others to not notice that this was reiterated endlessly elsewhere, or should we give people a tool that frees their time to do other useful things? If having dozens of different wordings for the same thing is so wanted, we could add macros. `__WHATHAVEYOUTRIED__` would expand to a variety of versions asking what you have tried...

Comment: When dealing with crap questions I often post helpful but quite mean comments just because I'm tired of typing the same over and over again about their crappy, vulnerable and deprecated code. Canned comments would make me write a nicer and more helpful comment once and just repost it every time. And not leaving a comment is definitely not the solution... if you post vulnerable code, would you like not being told about it just because there aren't any canned comments and everyone is just tired of retyping the same over and over again ?

Comment: Strongly disagree. I'm sick of copy-pasting from notepad !

Answer (score 23):

I think yes, let us have canned comments!

And not only, or even mainly, because of the convenience aspect, but rather because it would likely lead to a net gain in content quality. Here's why I say this:

Well-written, constructive canned comments would probably displace a bunch of not-so-good, snarky, hastily written comments. For example, I use the following as one of my standard replies in [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se):

> The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

This displaces my earlier crappy and lazy hand-typed variations on a common theme:

> What hvae you treid?

or

> Plaese show us your code else we cant help.

or

> This inst a free code writing service. Go **** yourself.

People may not like canned comments, and admittedly, they're not as great content as nicely personalised, genuinely felt comments with a pretty bow on top.

But that's *not the real alternative*. **In most cases, the alternative is a poor comment. Displacing those with a good canned comment would be a huge net benefit.**

Note that the close-vote "comment" that appears when a question gets closed is a form of this  and it's helpful; but it only appears once the question is already closed, which can take some time — and if the OP responds to it adequately, more waiting for reopen votes ensues. Instead, the feedback should be available earlier, and it should be made easy for folks to give this feedback — without having to install third-party apps (good as they may be).

Comment: "In most cases, the alternative is a poor comment. Displacing those with a good canned comment would be a huge net benefit." - heavily disagree. You're replacing crap of one kind with crap of a different kind. Often the only _actual_ useful comments are the personalized ones (when telling people they suck, point out where they _specifically_ suck). Most questions where a canned comment would be helpful would probably benefit just as much from a close reason; thus posting a canned comment becomes redundant. But it might discourage people from writing actually helpful, personalized comments.

Comment: All true, but missing the point. Many questions specifically suck in the same way. At some point I realised I was repeatedly retyping completely interchangeable variations on the same comment to a bunch of questions. Is that "personalised"? Is that useful? No. I much prefer my canned comment, which is well thought through.

Comment: _suck in the same way._  +1 for that

Comment: If the questions suck in the same way that's a sign there should just be a close reason for them. All the example comments currently given in this question and the answers more or less match the existing close reasons (unclear, broad, mcve), what more does a canned comment offer that's not part of the close reason already? And I don't even disagree that _some_ canned comments could be useful in the hands of experienced users, but there are already userscripts for that, and I doubt giving that ability to the masses would be a good thing.

Comment: What more does a canned comment offer? It shows up right away. Don't have to wait for 5 close votes before getting actionable feedback (and 5 reopen votes if you react to that feedback).

Comment: Don't forget the usual `Welcome to [insert site here]! This questions seems to be [insert reason here] and you should [insert action here].`, being the `reason` as invalid, off-topic on this site, duplicate, .... and the action can be edit, improve, post on other site..........

Answer (score 7):

I think it is a very good suggestion.  Especially if it only pre-loads the comment field and does *not* auto-submit it.  That way one can choose the closest message and edit it to better fit the situation.  Some messages should be customized like the first two of these:

1. The question is ambiguous or unclear.  Please clarify *[the specific area]*.
2. The question does not clearly describe the problem.  Improve it by *[showing expected output]* *[showing actual output]* *[providing sample input data]* *[showing missing code]*
3. There appears to be no question asked.  Please edit your post and ask a  question.

Comment: I want pre-select and auto-submit!

Comment: If we do have canned comments, I think they should not be cold. They should be warm and not demanding. These comments listed here are cold and can easily be seen as very harsh. If a comment is clear and friendly, the user is more likely to take it as help, rather than just criticism.

Comment: I like the idea, I don't like the wording on the comments. But nice one!