# Why am I receiving down votes for this question and how can I improve it?

Tags: support, specific-question

Previously I posted a similar question with rather lengthy code, so it was downvoted.

I worked on it and narrowed down the area I was stuck, but this time I was downvoted continuously.

The link to the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748434/custom-adaper-class-for-custom-list-view-in-android). Please help me improve it and let me know where I am lacking?

Comment: I really don't think people should be downvoting even this meta post. I mean, this is a new user genuinely reaching out trying to get help on how to be a constructive contributing member. Looking at their question, while it might need some help, it's infinitely better than we see from most new users these days and clearly show an effort to post a well formatted question. Seriously people, I get it that we're all tired of cleaning up crap posts but don't take it out on people that are trying.

Comment: I have an error....that all errors are created equal....and no text need be displayed that we may discriminate between them....

Comment: @TechnikEmpire it became a standard to post a question on meta why your post was downvoted. It works like magic - one meta post and here you go 30 upvotes for an average question. So soon more people would start asking the same question - why downvotes, then it would transform to questions about downvotes on meta question and so on.

Comment: @SalvadorDali it does seem to be a side effect. The user now has tons of rep, pretty sure they had next to none when they first posted this. But still, it's not like the user is part of some conspiracy to get rep fast. The same people who were hammering the original question with downvotes followed it here and started downvoting it too, which is why I made my original comment. So what if people are being perhaps too generous with their upvotes now, that's the power this site gives them, let them use it.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> Please help me improve it and let me know where am I lacking?

First, the folks casting the downvotes may be different than the folks casting the close votes. There's no way to tell why someone downvoted sans them leaving you a comment and telling you.

If you click on the *Close(3)* link, you will see three people voted to close because:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers.

I *think* that's partially due to:

> *"but while creating the adapter class I am facing some issues..."*

In the above (and the remainder of the question that follows), there's not really a clear problem statement.

You did say:

> *"but in the constructor I was not able to pass them all."*

But that not clear and it's not easy to understand.

Then you provide:

> *"I get an error that Cannot resolve method super(...)"*

In this case, it's not clear what the error is. You should provide an exact error message, and not blank out relevant information with elipses.

So I think you could improve the question by clearly stating what the problem is, and clearly stating what error you are encountering.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look :)

Comment: The OP doesn't have 250 rep, so can't see the *"Close(3)"* link

Comment: @psubsee2003 - that's important feedback. My gut tells me users should be able to get the feedback at any level. Since they can't follow the link, then maybe a private message in their inbox would do the trick?

Comment: @jww I'm just the messenger - but viewing close votes (on your own post) is a privilege.  There is a proposal on MSE to change this: [View an Alert on Close Votes for New Users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247851/view-an-alert-on-close-votes-for-new-users)

Comment: @psubsee2003 - no problem. It was useful information, thanks.

Comment: @jww: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283246/119775

Comment: Good answer, however generally speaking instead of stating what the problem *is*, would be better to say what you're trying to *achieve*. See XY Problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @psubsee2003 - [Please allow new users to view close reasons on their questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254211/173448)