# How to access MCVE comment snippets

Tags: support

Several times during my perusal of review queues I've seen what appear to be premeditated responses to the poster, such as ones asking for an MCVE. All of these comments have multiple links to SO resources and look oddly similar to one another, making me highly skeptical that people rewrite these every time they post them.

*e.g.*

[image: example]

I've looked over the SO help pages out of a strange feeling that I saw something like this while reading them over before, but found nothing.

This leads to my question: do such premeditated comment snippets exist for usage and if so, how can I access them? If they don't, then I'd like this to turn into a feature request for their addition. I think that some shorthand notation to write out in a comment that would invoke such a snippet would help speed up queue processing times.

Comment: That is a horrible comment. It doesn't say anything at all about what is actually wrong with the question. Hell, it isn't even grammatically correct. "Here's a scatter shot of resources that may or may not help you"

Comment: Sorry, guys! I didn't notice those resources. My bad.

Comment: Related: [May we have some “canned comments”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283114/may-we-have-some-canned-comments)

Comment: Also, I didn't notice this earlier (was still waking up I guess), but... we write code for people _all the time_, and how-to style questions are not inherently off-topic. They just have to be well-defined (unambiguous, not open to interpretation) and reasonably-scoped (asking how to do one thing, not seven things wrapped up in one package). So yeah, that comment holds absolutely no value and is actively harmful. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't just "do" this.

It's fine to comment in general, but if all you're going to do is say, "Hey, you should read [these things](https://example.com) first [before we help you](https://example.com)", then it's not going to be a good use of anyone's time.

For cases where the question is otherwise good and on-topic, then you can comment and goad the OP into filling in a few cracks here and there, since that'd be all you realistically need to formulate an answer.

For cases like the one in your picture - where there isn't *any* real details - then you're going to want to vote to close and/or downvote.  Commenting isn't worth it in that context since it's not going to produce a meaningful or constructive result.

The OP should be coming here with enough information to answer the question; just VTC these kinds of questions if they're not coming with enough information.