# Is my downvoting criterion, based on useless titles, too strict?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I was quite surprised to see that I have downvoted questions approximately
three times as often as upvoting them. This seems to be a lot more than most users.

My strategy for downvoting pretty much boils down to 'is this post useful for other people with the same issue'. A key part of being useful is whether the post is realistically searchable by people with the same problem. Therefore, I downvote any question which has a vague/non-specific title such as this one:

> [image: Example question with the title "Why the code attached below isn't working?"]

Clearly, even if the question at hand is excellent inside (it isn't), it's going to be exceedingly difficult for anyone to find the information inside, given how vague the title is. So I downvote it.

Where possible, I try to edit the title into something more informative, but I don't always have the energy or motivation to do this for all posts, so I downvote them, even if the question inside seems to be reasonable.

Although it's up to me to decide how to use my votes, I do sometimes feel bad for being so strict with it and I always appreciate the input of more experienced users. Is this strategy useful for the site in the long run? Is it 'too harsh' for punishing new members?

Comment: As for the question, I wouldn't downvote the above just based on the title. I would edit the question to make the title more meaningful. If the content of the question is good, it is useful/helpful and demonstrates research, then you should be upvoting it not downvoting it.

Comment: that is completly normal, to have 2 or 3 times higher downvotes as upvotes, if you are a critcal user that hopes that downhotes help the user to improve

Comment: A bad title is a problem; you are allowed to downvote questions based on problems they have. Whether you *should* or not is a matter for your own judgement.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Except that the question/answer breakdown is across _all_ votes, that's not the downvote breakdown, that's just the vote breakdown.

Comment: @Nick my bad, indeed, I thought it was one line for the down and another for the up, with the related breakdown

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε IT was that way prior the profile view update a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: "*I was quite surprised to see that I have downvoted questions approximately three times as often as upvoting them.*" sort of off-topic but I've been wondering what my statistics are here. However, I don't know how to look it up. The profile just lists upvotes/downvote count and then (unqualified) votes on questions/answer. How do I get a breakdown of upvote/downvote per questions/answers?

Comment: Some people [1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=topactivity) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11682469/jeanne-dark?tab=topactivity) have higher standards than others. That's not a problem. I believe Eric once said that one of his upvotes was a mistake.

Comment: @Nick I don't think we had the breakdown even before the profile change. At least I assume that's what you refer to. The stats were the same then - total count of upvotes, total count of downvotes, total count of *votes* on questions, total count of *votes* on answers. I've never seen a breakdown of up/down votes per question/answer.

Comment: @VLAZ Huh.... looking back (at screenshots), you appear to be correct, the layout was just much better, it didn't have more information, I stand corrected

Comment: I do follow this same strategy, however, I'm always willing to be surprised by a good high quality question having an awful title that simply needs a nudge.

Comment: Looking at how many posts that are closed or unanswered of the total (something like 80% iirc), I think all of us ought to have a lot more down-votes than up-votes.

Comment: Also note that if you spend time in review queues, especially Close Votes and Low Quality Answers, you're more likely to find posts you'll want to downvote.

Comment: 1) do you comment why you are down-voting; 2) how often do you edit these titles yourself to circumvent others like you; 3) do you go back to check for edits to see if the question has improved and remove your down-vote? anonymous sniping (especially new users) with down-votes and no explanation is just as annoying as bad questions and not reading "how to ask"

Comment: 1) never. I used to, however i found this practice to more often than not lead to an argument, not a solution. 2) never. I don't feel I'm in a position to guess what people who have this problem might search for. 3) Not unless they reply to a comment I've left. If teh post is a good, useful, post, it will have a positive score in the long run regardless of whether or not I remove my downvote. Individual users are not the arbiters of whether or not content is useful or not, it's an aggregate score. You don't need a specific individual (other than the OP) to return to save a useful post.

Comment: However, i think it's important to note that i *do* leave comments when i think the OP can improve their post, which includes when i think they have an unclear title and i have a suggestion that might help them fix it; regardless of whether or not i've casted a downvote or plan to.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Could we please be a bit nicer to curating users, while we are at it? Perhaps that would make them feel safe enough to post constructive criticism. Really, it's telling that this is actually [a notable reason for not giving advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/5349916).

Comment: "...I downvote them, even if the question inside seems to be reasonable." That might be the heart of the problem. Just going for the title alone and ignoring the rest of the content doesn't look like it gives a lot of useful information. Surely search engines don't work like that.

Comment: @Lundin "Looking at how many posts that are closed or unanswered of the total (something like 80% iirc), I think all of us ought to have a lot more down-votes than up-votes." Not for me. I arrive at useful content mostly through a search engine and that is already a selected content and typically worth an upvote. The "garbage" I just don't get to see mostly. There are a lot of low quality posts on SO but they aren't really seen often. I upvote roughly two times more than I downvote and I feel like this is close to optimal.

Comment: @Trilarion Yeah it's subjective depending on how you are using the site. Users who do a lot of user moderation will end up with a lot more close- and down-votes than others.

Comment: Upvoted. I finally realize that all these users with meaningless drive-by downvotes could have their reasons. I still wonder which part of them didn't like the color of my avatar. As it was said, a constructive way is to just edit the title. It's a normal thing and not considered rude, to my knowledge.

Comment: @David - “If you are downvoting before leaving a comment suggesting an improvement -- then you are part of the problem, not part of the solution” - I would only do this if I wanted to be attacked every time I provided feedback to a bad question or answer. Curating users are absolutely abused and nothing is done to those “new users” when it happens.

Comment: @Trilarion: I have the opposite experience. Most search engine hits are low-scored duplicates with one or two non-comprehensive answers or non-answers (usually without any indication of what the canonical question is).

Comment: @PeterMortensen How good are the titles of your search engine hits? Maybe it's the opposite effect of the one described here: low quality content but with high quality titles.

Comment: *"I was quite surprised to see that I have downvoted questions approximately three times as often as upvoting them"* well it depends on the tag, but this sounds about right. There is just way too much low quality material coming in to be able to decode the Matrix. But still, downvoting because of a title is not the best route to that result. If you don't want to fix it yourself, you might want to skip. Then again, doing these kind of downvotes *is* the freedom the site grants you so who are we to judge?

Comment: would you downwote [Leonard of Quirm](https://wiki.lspace.org/Leonard_of_Quirm)? ("Oddly enough, his creativity seems to stop when needed to give appealing names to his inventions")

Comment: Leonard's names tended toward dull, but descriptive. His genius wasn't marketing to be sure, but *Going-Under-The-Water-Safely-Device* pretty much nailed it.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487/211627

Comment: @MisterMiyagi agreed, and I didn't mean to be flippant, but it strikes me as completely counter-production (for SO and StackExchange) to look at doling out downvotes as a badge of honor and something that should be refined. Instead of the focus on "How many downvotes for ... I gave today.", from a governance standpoint should be "How many people did I help today?" Granted there are some questions where downvotes are appropriate, but absent abuse, not until a suggestion and opportunity to cure is given. Just my $.02 from 7+ years of watching this problem grow like weeds in a vacant lot.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Believe me, I don’t see downvotes as a „badge of honor“. But unless  you want indiscriminate downvotes, it *is* something to be refined. As someone who finds most (as in, hundred times more) of their answers via searching existing content, I firmly believe that rating content for what it is helps tons of people. Seeing how many suggestions and advice and opportunities posters already have available, I see little point in stalling an action that can easily be reversed. Just my $.02 cents from some years of not watching and getting abused for the effort to help people.

Comment: @nbk I find that shocking. It indicates that you don’t use upvotes nearly enough. My own upvote count is several times higher than my downvote count because I don’t just provide negative feedback, I also provide positive reinforcement, where appropriate. Your feedback seems seriously unbalanced.

Comment: no @KonradRudolph i mostly view question of new users, which tend to be bad till very bad. Hence i vote to close a lot and if the question lacks in deratil are missing the mre i use the downvote button, simply because most people don't read the tag info or have read the how to ask. the same goes for, they ask a question, but they don't ask themselves can the reader who has nothing to do with my project understand what i am asking, but here i blame the schools, which should teach such things

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your downvoting behaviour is perfectly fine.

---

This is how the post you are referring to looks in my default search engine:

[image]

It plainly would not matter if there were a nice description in the question body, because most of it is not visible during search. Many other searches and views do not even show anything but the title.
A poor title hurts long-term usefulness immensely.

Rating a question as "not useful" because the title is non-descriptive is reasonable. Downvoting is thus reasonable as well.

---

> Where possible, I try to edit the title into something more informative, but I don't always have the energy or motivation to do this for all posts, so I downvote them, even if the question inside seems to be reasonable.
>
> Although it's up to me to decide how to use my votes, I do sometimes feel bad for being so strict with it and I always appreciate the input of more experienced users. Is this strategy useful for the site in the long run? Is it 'too harsh' for punishing new members?

The simple truth is that there is way more content to curate than people who do curation. Every bit of curation – be it categorization or restoration – helps and is useful for the site.
Try not to feel bad when you did not do *everything* – accept that you did *something* at least. The day has only 24h and you have only so much energy to spend. There is just no way you could do *everything*, and punishing yourself over not meeting such an unrealistic goal will hurt yourself.

If you do feel that this happens very often and want to help people improve, consider to prepare a canned comment: a pre-written comment that you just copy/paste on such questions. This reduces your effort to help people, and it can help detach yourself from inappropriate reactions; if it helps ten people, it is easier to stomach the one that reacted badly.
Consider also to *follow* posts that you put such comments on. This allows you to revert your vote once the content has been improved. Seeing a post improve due to the advice you gave is important to keep you motivated – and thus help you improve the site in the long run.

Comment: Accepting this as I like the suggestion of following posts and removing the downvote when they are updated.

Comment: Canned comments are not easy to get right. See for example, *[Can we have some site approved canned comments to match the new CoC and welcoming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371410/)* (more the answers, not so much the title (apropos)), *[Let's talk about my (canned) comments for bad questions by New Contributors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372945/)*, and *[May we have some "canned comments"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283114/)*.

Answer (score 69):

Downvoting a question because it has useless title is a good reason for the downvote. However, it is preferred that you edit and improve the question if possible. It's better than downvoting.

You define criteria for downvoting. We can't tell you anything more than the tooltip already does. Downvote posts that you think are not useful, are unclear or in low quality in any other way. Remember to upvote posts you find useful too.

Comment: Right, you can downvote however you see fit but if the reason is non-obvious based on the tooltip don't be expecting someone to know exactly how they're supposed to improve their question. This specific question, of course, has more issues than just the title, but when the question is otherwise excellent and it's one specific issue (and as you said preferably addressed with an edit), the point becomes more salient.

Comment: For user438383, also consider this: as Shog9 once said, writing titles is hard; if a question is otherwise excellent, why would you want to make it even less visible than the poor title has already made it, by adding a downvote on top of it? Surely you'd want such a question to gain more traction and hopefully help the asker find an answer if they haven't found one already. The best way to do that is to edit the question and just give it a better title (*never mind* any hypothetical concerns you might have of feeding someone a fish or whatever, it's OK, I promise).

Comment: I disagree that a useless title is a good reason to downvote exactly because one should just edit the title instead (and it should be quite trivial to do if you believe the author could've easily written a better title). One can downvote for any reason (other than one targeting users), which may make it a "valid" reason, but that doesn't mean the reason is *good*. There are so many other much more fundamental problems that a post can have, that downvoting for something you can easily fix just doesn't make sense if our goal is a high-quality library of questions and answers.

Comment: @BoltClock it would be easy to leave a comment explaining the reason for the downvote, but I stopped counting how often we were told not to do it. “Downvote and move on” was the declared policy. Of course, that implies that it is not obvious for the questioner how to improve the question.

Comment: @Holger: I never liked that policy myself. It's certainly good advice for dealing with questions you don't feel are worth your time, but not every question is like that. Sometimes it genuinely doesn't hurt to do so. Comments exist for a reason, why not use them? If it pisses someone off to be given an explanation why their question was downvoted, flag *their* response and move on - if a would-be voter/commenter doesn't want to deal with *that* potential fallout, then fair enough... otherwise, if they're alright, might as well say some words.

Comment: @Holger "“Downvote and move on” was the declared policy." Not really the declared policy, I'd say. Of course you can do it, but nobody will remove your comments if you happen to comment on the quality of something. At least I hope nobody does. Basically you're free to comment or not to comment.

Answer (score 22):

Voting is a content rating system based on *your own assessment* regarding the quality and usefulness of a question or answer. If it is your assessment that such a title hampers the usefulness of the question, then it's in your right to downvote it. There is no need nor interest to overcomplicate this.

> I do sometimes feel bad for being so strict with it and I always appreciate the input of more experienced users.

For one, by voting we are rating content, not users. If you make your votes dependent on the author, you are contributing to a misguided post score, while sending a false signal to the author and future visitors. Providing feedback is complementary at best, which can be done regardless of how you vote. Same applies to editing the question.

See also:

- [What really amounts to "be nice to new contributors"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379704/what-really-amounts-to-be-nice-to-new-contributors)
- [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 17):

Poor titles make a post less useful because it makes it harder to find, and it makes it harder to tell whether a question is relevant to you or not. That makes a question less clear and less useful, both of which are reasons to downvote.

On the other hand, I personally prefer to salvage a question with editing if possible. If you can see a good way to fix the post by editing, that's probably better than downvoting; otherwise, feel free to downvote.

Comment: The most annoying is still, when they stuff the error message into there - but not repeat it inside the content area, because one cannot nicely copy & paste from the title area, unless somehow grabbing it at the right spot (it's not too handy). +1 for the appearance in the whole listing.

Comment: @MartinZeitler there is a trick for copying titles (it's for links in general) - hold down Alt and then you can click and mark any part of the link without activating it. Of course this shouldn't be an excuse for making somebody copy the title - that should only contain a summary of the problem, everything needed should be in the question itself.

Comment: Re *"Poor titles make a post less useful"*: Indeed they do. Especially in search engine results.

Comment: I often edit the question titles, often with an edit message of "non-useless title" if it was the only thing besides tags I changed, and the original was truly useless like "assembly language help".  I know it's a little snarky, but it's also true and I'm showing them how to fix it at the same time, if they ever look at the edit history.

Comment: @VLAZ: In KDE (and other window managers that allow it), I prefer to have alt+left-click reposition the window, like click+drag in the title bar but without having to aim or have the title bar visible.  To copy titles it can help to make the window wider so there's room outside the fixed width that SO limits to.  (100% agreed that none of this ever justifies having crucial information or a verbatim error message be present *only* in the title.)

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the tip... that's quite the opposite behavior, as in a shell terminal.

Answer (score 9):

The main purpose of downvoting is rating content and you can vote as you see fit.

However, not all content is worthy of a downvote. A main problem with posts that deserve downvotes is that their essence is bad and they can usually be only improved by the OP.

If the post is otherwise good, on-topic, and not blatantly an obvious duplicate, but it just needs some improvements that can be easily done by anyone else besides the OP, then downvoting is probably not the best option.

For instance, if a post has poor English, or a poor title, or similar, but otherwise it is good and contributes to the site, then you can either fix it yourself, leave a comment to the OP, or just leave the post alone. Someone else may come along and fix it.

This is also the reason why there is an *edit* feature which also rewards users reputation for editing. We want to improve what can be improved into a good post.

There are so many poor posts here that downvoting ones that can be saved is waste of a vote.

---

You don't have to worry about your upvote/downvote ratio. Users that moderate more tend to have way more downvotes than upvotes. In my case, of total votes cast, less than 10% were upvotes.

Comment: _"There are so many poor posts here that downvoting ones that can be saved is waste of a vote."_ No. There's no vote quota, and there is absolutely no reason not to downvote something because there are other "worse" posts out there. Judge a post on its own (lack of) merits.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no vote quota"? I run out of votes frequently, @Cerbrus.

Comment: @Cerbrus I often ran out of daily votes, so yes there is a limit on votes and I try to spend them on really bad posts and not on ones that only have some minor issues.

Comment: Hm, I've only ever ran out of comment votes. Are you sure there's also a max quota for downvotes? Still, I think a better suggestion is to not downvote something that has already received enough downvotes, and can be close-voted, in that case.

Comment: [Yes @Cerbrus, I'm sure.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: I guess I'm more easily deterred by the bad questions, then ;-)

Comment: i do routinely hit the downvote cap, but it's rarely a reason in my case to avoid downvoting things i feel deserve it. Obviously, if your activity results in you hitting the cap often enough for it to be a problem, being more picky could be useful. You do what fits best for you.

Comment: @Cerbrus Please read again what I wrote. I said, if the question is a good one (opposite of a bad one) and only has minor issues that can be easily fixed by other people, then downvoting seems to be over the top. If the only thing wrong with the question is a title, why would you downvote such question and not just improve the title?

Comment: Because it needs to be improved to be useful. It therefore isn’t useful, right now.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Depends on how bad the title is.

Comment: @Cerbrus It is just a title. Yes, title is extremely important, but title is just a summary of a problem. If the rest of the question is good, then title could be pure nonsense and one can still rewrite the title into a good title. Of course, in real life if the title is nonsense, then the question will probably be of same quality, but again if the title is the only problem then fixing the title instead downvoting seems like obvious choice.

Comment: Unless you make a list of all your down votes and frequently go through them to up voted improved content, it isn't a good idea to down vote things that aren't useful now but have problems that are easily corrected.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this strategy useful for the site in the long run?

No, it's not. You downvote based on what you perceive as downside of a post. That is your right, you can vote your conscience.

**However**, to be useful to the site, you need to *tell* people why you downvoted them, otherwise they will not improve. They will just become resentful of the random internet person that downvoted them with no obvious reason.

Punishment without a way for the punished to improve is cruel and inhuman. Please note that *you* used the term punishment, so even if downvotes might not be thought of as punishment, I think we agree that being docked internet points does not feel good and you want to use this feeling for behavior adjustment. So far so good. But your whole strategy becomes meaningless, the moment you don't tell people what you punish them for.

If you want to teach people, random punishment without obvious reason only teaches hate and resentment. To teach anything, you would be a good example, offer specific advice and *maybe* if you think punishment is a good teaching method (debatable), *then* you can punish someone, after they saw your example, heard your advice and *ignored* it.

Comment: Ironic that the "tell people why you downvoted them" answer has a downvote without a reason why :S

Comment: You shouldn't tell people why you downvoted them, you should instruct them how they can improve their post. That leaving a comment reason wasn't included in the question, isn't an indication that commenting should be avoided; it's simply a different topic entirely.

Comment: FWIW, for many questions that are downvoted (and occasionally some upvoted) I can't figure out why they got the votes they did. And while some downvoters pay attention to question edits and remove no longer valid downvotes, many do not. I agree that this behaviour is harmful to the site.

Comment: See also [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin), just because nobody have linked to it. — talk about down vote being punishment is also problematic, although alright OP said that first.

Comment: Ideally you downvote posts, not people / users.  Even though it's the people who post with useless titles that are wasting your time summarizing their question for them, especially when they didn't even try at all and just titled "Assembly language help" or "help me with this" or some crap.

Answer (score -6):

I agree with @nvoight whe they say:

> *To teach anything, you would be a good example, offer specific advice and maybe if you think punishment is a good teaching method (debatable), then you can punish someone, after they saw your example, heard your advice and ignored it.*

I tend to use this exact method, the only difference is that the downvote after being ignored is not so much a punishment, but a way to signal a bad post. I don't care to punish people, but the *good users* (and I'm pretentiously including myself in this category) should care for the overall quality of the site.

Comment: If your vote is because they didn't follow your advice... it's punishment regardless of what you call it. These two actions need to be disconnected.

Comment: @KevinB There is a difference, you surely understand that, and OP will also. And it's not because of the advice *per se*, it's if I feel that without changes the post is bad and deserving of DV, one can interpret that as punishment, I surely don't.

Comment: If the content deserved a DV after they ignored your advice, surely it deserved a DV before they ignored your advice, isn't it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, the point is you should help improve the content before you hastily downvote, at least that's what I do. And I do downvote, 30% of my votes are DVs