# Why doesn't Stack Overflow meta sort the answers by votes like in the main site?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

The main site, sometime ago, changed the rules to sort the answers by upvotes, and not show the accepted one on top. Why wasn't this also implemented on meta?

[Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415399/6865932) (at the time of publishing).

Comment: See [Outdated Answers: accepted answer is now unpinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352), there is [some discussion there as to the usefulness of keeping the accepted answer pinned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411376/100297). But mostly: Because unpinning is an experiment, and the company (rightly, in my mind) didn't apply this change to everything at once to begin with.

Comment: [Relevant discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370716/348196) about unpinning the accepted answer on Meta Stack _Exchange_.

Comment: @41686d6564 It's indeed very relevant, it appears that more likely than not, this feature will not be extended to meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my speculation about the reason, but I think I'm right: on meta, votes are normally used to indicate agreement or disagreement, not relevance or usefulness. There are very highly-downvoted answers to many high-profile questions which are nonetheless the *most* relevant answer to the question e.g. due to being written by somebody involved in the question, or a representative from Stack Overflow (the company).

For an example, there's [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505/12299000) where the accepted answer has -214 votes (as of writing), but clearly should be pinned to the top since it is the only answer to that question from an authoritative source.

Comment: It makes sense, [Martin Pieters has a different reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415488/why-doesnt-meta-so-sorts-the-answers-by-votes-like-in-the-main-site#comment890936_415488) for this though, what do you think?

Comment: @anastaciu Martijn's answer in the comments is not speculative, so you can give it higher weight than mine; if you like, read mine as justifying why it's good that meta works this way and shouldn't be changed in the same way as Stack Overflow was.

Comment: There's also some posts that use accepted answers as a way to pin a table of contents, particularly on _huge_ bug report questions

Comment: You don't need to speculate, it is even documented that [voting on meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). By extension it makes less sense to sort things by vote on meta.

Comment: @Gimby I'm not speculating that people vote for different reasons on meta - I'm speculating about the reason(s) that the accepted answer is pinned to the top on meta, which is what the question is about. Yes, it does follow "by extension" but that extension is a form of speculation; I do not know for certain that that is the reason that the people responsible made it like that.